# Echo custom field value in shortcode function

Tags: functions, shortcode, array

I must be doing something wrong here. I want to display the custom fields **"pw_featured_note"** & **"pw_featured_price"**

Here is my code so far

```
function featured() {

query_posts('post_type=property&posts_per_page=2');
    if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    echo "<div class=\"singlefeatured group\">";
    if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pw_featured_property', true) ) ;
    echo "<a href='".get_permalink()."'>";
    the_post_thumbnail('home-thumb');
    echo "</a>";
    echo "<h2><a href='".get_permalink()."'>".get_the_title()."</a></h2>";
    echo "<p>".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pw_featured_property', true)."</p>";
    echo "<p> goodbye </p>";
    echo "</div>";
    endwhile;
    endif; 
    wp_reset_query();

}

add_shortcode('featuredproperty', 'featured');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *What is your question?* Plus, never `echo` something in a shortcode function, use `return $string;` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, I've removed `query_posts` and used `get_posts` instead because I'm not sure if `query_posts` will work in a shortcode and using `get_posts` is safer.

```
function featured()
{
    $posts = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'property', 'posts_per_page' => 2));

    if(isset($posts) && !empty($posts))
    {
        foreach($posts as $post)
        {
            echo "<div class=\"singlefeatured group\">";

            //I wasn't sure what you wanted to get inside this if statement, please correct this
            if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pw_featured_property', true))
            {
                echo "<a href='".get_permalink($post->ID)."'>";
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'home-thumb');
                echo "</a>";
            }
            echo "<h2><a href='".get_permalink($post->ID)."'>".get_the_title($post->ID)."</a></h2>";
            echo "<p>".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pw_featured_property', true)."</p>";
            echo "<p> goodbye </p>";
            echo "</div>";
        }

    }
}

add_shortcode('featuredproperty', 'featured');
```

Just make sure you check what comes inside the inner `if` statement, I've just pulled in the `a` tag.

Comment: You're welcome mate... Just one more thing, as you mentioned in the question, where are `pw_featured_note` & `pw_featured_price` fields in the code? I assume you figured that out!

Answer (score 0):

I can see from your code that you opened two 'if', but closed only one.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, although it's working better with just the one closed "if"

Comment: The second if line is also invalid, it has a semi-colon after it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your `functions.php`:

```
function foobar_func( $atts ){
     global $post;
     $key=$atts['name'];
     if(empty($key)) return;
    return get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

And for display, add `[foobar name=custom_field_name]` to your post or page.